# Query CloudKit database with multiple record types

Tags: ios, swift, cloudkit

I have a cloud kit database set up and am trying to query against it.  It looks like predicates won't work for what I'm trying to do.

In SQL the query would look something like this:

SELECT type1
FROM table1, table2
WHERE table1.columnA = table2.columnB

Also, similar to:

```
NSPredicate(format: "%K == %K" "key1", "key2") but that doesn't work either.
```

Again, because I am trying to match up key values I don't think predicates will work.  Does anyone have any solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you cannot query multiple recordType's with one query in CloudKit. You need to query 1 recordType first and then use that result for querying the 2nd recordType. The predicate you suggested only works if both fields are in the same recordType

Comment: Seems like a basic database function that is missing.  I ended up passing the information i wanted to query against as variables then wrote the predicate appropriately.

Comment: This is quite common for nosql databases. For a compact explanation see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL

Comment: Ah.  I was thinking of it in relational database terms.  Thanks for the info.  Makes a difference as I'm going.

Comment: Beware in the WWDC 2015 they make a specific mention not to nest queries within queries too. So don't use the convenience API for this.

Answer (score 0):

You should check out Apple's [CloudCaptions](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/CloudCaptions/Introduction/Intro.html) samples code. They create wrappers for each `CKRecord` type, and have convenience methods to load the relationships.

Hopefully Apple adds better searching functionality this year!